# Nested Route With SideBar

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I am facing error

Example image
[image]

How to implement we have left side have a side bar and right side is operation page
dashboard page have navigate route replace that page left side is still every page how to implement that. I am using getx can u share me example or something resourses.Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: Please provide some tried code .

Comment: How did you create the side navigation?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this package `https://pub.dev/packages/side_navigation`. Basically the **Dashboard (right)** view is just a list of widgets and on tap of the **Left Navigation** items the index is returned. There wont be `Naviagtor.push` since it will not show new `Scaffold`.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter (as far as i am aware) does not have a router-outlet like Angular does, but flutter does a good job context and view swapping, where routing is not always necessary, which is how the native side navigation does.

In this example you use the state of your parent to manage what view to show, but each of your views could have the their own navigation stack internally.

```
...
Scaffold(
    body: Row(
        children: [
            Flex(
                3,
                child: SideNavigation(
                    onItemClick: (index) => {
                        setState(() {
                            _currentView = index;
                        })
                    }
                ),
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: [View1(), View2(), View3()][_currentView]
            ),
        ],
    ),
);
...
```